# plotting markers on top of axes

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am tying to make a (x,y) scatter plot using numpy.  Right now the axes start from (0,0) and extend to align with the range of the data.  I need to plot two points which lie on the x=0 line.

Currently it appears the symbols are being drawn before the axes, and subsequently are being truncated by the axes.  I would like this to appear on top of the axes. I believe I can do something with a 'label' however I cannot find any method to make this work.

The markers are somewhat visible, however they are a decently crucial component of the visualization.  If someone has a work around this would be wonderful.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can turn off the clip flag of the line object created by plt.plot.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = np.array([0,1,2,3,4,5,6])
y = np.array([0,2,0,4.5,0.5,2,3])

line = plt.plot(x,y,'o')[0]
line.set_clip_on(False)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. This is initially what I was thinking, but I ended up using GMT to make the plot for the review.  This deserves an upvote.

Comment: I believe this is now just a kw argument, `plt.plot(x,y,'o', clip_on=False)`

Comment: For later versions of Matplotlib, follow [ondra.cifka's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50078988/6211109).

Comment: The clipping work fine but it violates the xlim. If you have any data beyond the xlim, it still gets plotted since clipping is turned off (python 3.9). Any solution to that?

Answer (score 21):

To actually make the markers appear on top of the axes, you can use `zorder`:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = np.array([0,1,2,3,4,5,6])
y = np.array([0,2,0,4.5,0.5,2,3])

plt.plot(x, y, 'o', zorder=10, clip_on=False)
plt.xlim(0, 6)
plt.ylim(0, 4.5)
plt.show()
```

[image: The result]

Comment: set `zorder=10, clip_on=False`

Answer (score 1):

I think you're after [`plt.axis([xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax])`](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.axis):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = np.array([0,1,2,3,4,5,6])
y = np.array([0,2,0,4.5,0.5,2,3])
plt.plot(x,y,'o')
plt.axis()
# (0.0, 6.0, 0.0, 4.5)
plt.axis([-.5,6.5,-.5,5])
plt.show()
```

[image]

You could programatically retrive the current axis with `plt.axis()` and then subtract/add a small margin on, and re-set it.

Comment: Also take a look at `pyplot.xlim()` and `pyplot.ylim()`.

Comment: Thanks. Both of these solutions are pretty much what I am looking for.  Either will be perfect.  Sorry about the no upvotes, I'm still new here and don't have that privilege.