# R - Plotting markers on top of axes

Tags: r, plot

Is there a parameter in plot() that allows the markers at x > 0, y = 0 to be displayed on top of the x axis and likewise for markers at x = 0, y > 0 on the y axis?

I've gone through all the previous questions and found a solution for Python only.
[plotting markers on top of axes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9220088/plotting-markers-on-top-of-axes)

I tried to post my graph but it Stack Overflow indicates I need 10 reputation in order to post images.

Comment: link to the other solution? I'm not sure what you want

Comment: Perfect. I used par(xpd) = TRUE. Cheers.

Comment: You can pass it directly in plot, too, `plot(c(0,1), xaxs = 'i', cex = 5, xpd = NA)`